# I have error when give fire-base --version. error- firebase' is not recognized

Tags: angularfire

why this error? I have error when give `firebase --version`. I already install latest `nodeJS`.

Error like this-

> 'firebase' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Please provide some code so that others can have a look at what is going wrong. Simply stating the error gives no clue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **Firebase-Tools** to run command `firebase --version`

To install, run command:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

Comment: Next step indicates to do the fllowing:_
$ firebase login

I'm getting the same error message.... Getting frustrated.